# 'git restore .' 'git reset' does not work for "changes not staged"

Tags: git, git-submodules

My git version is 2.34.1

I am trying to checkout a release by given tag, I am working on this git repo https://gitee.com/EspressifSystems/esp-idf.git
my checkout command `git checkout v3.4.3 -b v3.4.3`

I get git status like:

```
On branch v4.3.4
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   components/bt/controller/lib_esp32 (new commits)
    modified:   components/bt/controller/lib_esp32c3_family (new commits)
    modified:   components/bt/host/nimble/nimble (new commits)
    modified:   components/esp_wifi/lib (new commits)
    modified:   components/lwip/lwip (new commits)
    modified:   components/mbedtls/mbedtls (new commits)
    modified:   components/mqtt/esp-mqtt (new commits)
    modified:   components/protobuf-c/protobuf-c (new commits)
    modified:   components/spiffs/spiffs (new commits)
    modified:   components/tinyusb/tinyusb (new commits)
    modified:   examples/peripherals/secure_element/atecc608_ecdsa/components/esp-cryptoauthlib (new commits)

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    components/bt/controller/lib_esp32c2/
    components/bt/controller/lib_esp32h2/
    components/esp_phy/
    components/heap/tlsf/
    components/ieee802154/
    components/openthread/
```

I have tried bellow:

1. `git restore .` to ignore everything
2. `git restore  components/bt/controller/lib_esp32` to ignore one specific item
3. `git reset --hard HEAD`
4. `git clean -d -f`

Above commands take no effects

as @phd reminds, those "not staged" belongs to submodules, I tried
5. `git submodule foreach git reset --hard;git status`

```
git submodule foreach git reset --hard;git status
Entering 'components/bootloader/subproject/components/micro-ecc/micro-ecc'
HEAD is now at d037ec8 Add note that uECC_VLI_NATIVE_LITTLE_ENDIAN affects key compatiblity
Entering 'components/bt/controller/lib_esp32'
HEAD is now at 8188c3b fix esp32 ke_mem.c assert(425d342)
Entering 'components/bt/controller/lib_esp32c3_family'
HEAD is now at d1c2082 fix adv report duplicate check
Entering 'components/bt/host/nimble/nimble'
HEAD is now at 64322688 Fixed compilation error for esp32c2 and esp32h2 when os_mbuf_free is called
Entering 'components/cmock/CMock'
HEAD is now at eeecc49 Merge pull request #312 from Skinner927/patch-1
Entering 'components/esp_wifi/lib'
HEAD is now at 1777992b esp_wifi:bugfix for wifi owe memory leak(98ffa91b)
Entering 'components/json/cJSON'
HEAD is now at d348621 chore: update version and changelog (#610)
Entering 'components/lwip/lwip'
HEAD is now at 3f5a04bc igmp/mld6: Fix on-demand timers to set LWIP_NUM_SYS_TIMEOUT_INTERNAL
Entering 'components/mbedtls/mbedtls'
HEAD is now at 9bb5effc3 ecp: Add support for hardware implementation of ECP routines
Entering 'components/mqtt/esp-mqtt'
HEAD is now at 89e5c60 fix: MQTT tick not starting on connect and switch to esp_timer
Entering 'components/protobuf-c/protobuf-c'
HEAD is now at f224ab2 ChangeLog: 1.4.0
Entering 'components/spiffs/spiffs'
HEAD is now at 0dbb3f7 Merge pull request #288 from igrr/bugfix/spiffs_readdir_errcode
Entering 'components/tinyusb/tinyusb'
HEAD is now at c1986586 remove unused submodules
Entering 'components/unity/unity'
HEAD is now at 7d2bf62 Merge pull request #363 from Deltrix/patch-1
Entering 'examples/build_system/cmake/import_lib/main/lib/tinyxml2'
HEAD is now at 7e8e249 Merge pull request #707 from SwiftEngineering/issue_706
Entering 'examples/peripherals/secure_element/atecc608_ecdsa/components/esp-cryptoauthlib'
HEAD is now at 985ea96 Merge branch 'feature/mbedtls-3.1' into 'master'
On branch v4.3.4
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   components/bt/controller/lib_esp32 (new commits)
    modified:   components/bt/controller/lib_esp32c3_family (new commits)
    modified:   components/bt/host/nimble/nimble (new commits)
    modified:   components/esp_wifi/lib (new commits)
    modified:   components/lwip/lwip (new commits)
    modified:   components/mbedtls/mbedtls (new commits)
    modified:   components/mqtt/esp-mqtt (new commits)
    modified:   components/protobuf-c/protobuf-c (new commits)
    modified:   components/spiffs/spiffs (new commits)
    modified:   components/tinyusb/tinyusb (new commits)
    modified:   examples/peripherals/secure_element/atecc608_ecdsa/components/esp-cryptoauthlib (new commits)

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    components/bt/controller/lib_esp32c2/
    components/bt/controller/lib_esp32h2/
    components/esp_phy/
    components/heap/tlsf/
    components/ieee802154/
    components/openthread/
```

Comment: Please, paste the screenshot as text in the question

Comment: `git reset --hard` is the big guns. Can you run `git status; git reset --hard; git status`? Paste the output in the question.

Comment: @eftshift0 my posted screenshot, is exactly the same `git status` before and after 'git reset --hard', that's the reason why I DONT UNDERSTAND, and create this question.

Comment: `modified: path (new commits)` means those paths are [tag:git-submodules]. You need to decide if you want to commit changes in these submodules to the superproject or you want to discard new commits in the submodules and revert them back to the commits store in the superproject.

Comment: @phd oh, good catch, I just tried 'git submodule foreach git reset --hard', but also not work, strange

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68049245/7976758 `git submodule update` to discard new commits. Or https://stackoverflow.com/a/61751340/7976758 `git restore . --recurse-submodules`

Comment: git restore . --recurse-submodules' works

Comment: @phd do you mind "answer my question", so I can ACCPET and close this. Thanks!

Comment: Upvote the answer(s) at the existing question(s).